# Arrange HTML description list's terms horizontaly

Tags: html, css

I have an auto-generated HTML `<dl>` tag with two `<dd>` tags, the list is automatically split into two. I want to be able to arrange the result horizontally in chronological order.

This is how I have it right now.

```
<dl class="filter-books">
  <dt><h3>Books</h3></dt>
    <dd class="col1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic_books[]" id="book_109" value="109" >
      <label class="book book-1" for="book_109"> Book 1 </label>
    </dd>

    <dd class="col1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic_books[]" id="book_96" value="96" >
      <label class="book book-2" for="book_96"> Book 2 </label>
    </dd>

    <dd class="col1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic_books[]" id="book_89" value="89" >
      <label class="book book-3" for="book_89"> Book 3 </label>
    </dd>

    <dd class="col2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic_books[]" id="book_16" value="16" >
      <label class="book book-4" for="book_16"> Book 4 </label>
    </dd>

    <dd class="col2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic_books[]" id="book_88" value="88" >
      <label class="book book-5" for="book_88"> Book 5 </label>
    </dd>

    <dd class="col2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic_books[]" id="book_98" value="98" >
      <label class="book book-6" for="book_98"> Book 6 </label>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

**CSS:**

```
dd { float: left; width: 45%; padding-bottom: 0.5em; margin-left: 1em; }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GxJm6/) of current display.

How I wish it to be is how the display is in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2P85/). The HTML list in this fiddle has only been modified to show desired result.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Is the lenght of the list variable or is it known?

Comment: Yes the length of the list is known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the length of the list is known, the following will work: http://jsfiddle.net/u63jS/.

CSS:

```
dd {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%; 
    padding-bottom: 0.5em; 
    margin-left: 1em; 
}

dd:nth-of-type(-n + 3) {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

And, the following code will work in older browsers (e.g., IE6): http://jsfiddle.net/u63jS/1/.

```
dd {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%; 
    padding-bottom: 0.5em; 
    margin-left: 1em; 
}

dt + dd,
dt + dd + dd, 
dt + dd + dd + dd {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

Another, an unnecessarily complicated, but modern flexbox solution: http://jsfiddle.net/s6W5w/.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

.filter-books {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.filter-books > dt {
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.filter-books > dd {
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 50%;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.filter-books > dd:nth-of-type(1) {
    order: 1;
}

.filter-books > dd:nth-of-type(2) {
    order: 3;
}

.filter-books > dd:nth-of-type(3) {
    order: 5;
}

.filter-books > dd:nth-of-type(4) {
    order: 2;
}

.filter-books > dd:nth-of-type(5) {
    order: 4;
}

.filter-books > dd:nth-of-type(6) {
    order: 6;
}
```

Lastly, a solution that uses columns: http://jsfiddle.net/2Z9CT/.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

dl > dt {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

dl {
    margin-top: 25px;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count:2;
}

dl > dd {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: And if you want to keep your `col` classes, replace `dd:nth-of-type(-n + 3)` with `dd.col1` ... http://jsfiddle.net/FjY2n/

Comment: That's a good point @Jon P.  Personally, I see a lot of overuse of classes and divs.  I prefer to use a relationship structure among elements rather than polluting HTML with extra markup.

Answer (score 0):

This does it, but I don't know how you are generating the data.

```
<dl class="filter-books">
  <dt><h3>Books</h3></dt>
    <dd class="col1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic_books[]" id="book_109" value="109" >
      <label class="book book-1" for="book_109"> Book 1 </label>
    </dd>
    <dd class="col2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic_books[]" id="book_16" value="16" >
      <label class="book book-4" for="book_16"> Book 4 </label>
    </dd>
    <dd class="col1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic_books[]" id="book_96" value="96" >
      <label class="book book-2" for="book_96"> Book 2 </label>
    </dd>

    <dd class="col2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic_books[]" id="book_88" value="88" >
      <label class="book book-5" for="book_88"> Book 5 </label>
    </dd>

    <dd class="col1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic_books[]" id="book_89" value="89" >
      <label class="book book-3" for="book_89"> Book 3 </label>
    </dd>

    <dd class="col2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="topic_books[]" id="book_98" value="98" >
      <label class="book book-6" for="book_98"> Book 6 </label>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: The list is autogenerated, I cannot alter the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If jquery is allowed you can use `.wrapAll()` function. check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fovofeya/1/edit)**.

This jquery code will move all `dd` have class `col2`

```
$('dd.col2').wrapAll('<div class="sub-menu" />');
```

CSS used to fix the alignment.

```
.sub-menu{
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 40px;
    width: 48%;
}
.filter-books{position:relative;}
```